# Regex for specific number, ignoring other numbers

Tags: regex

I'm stuck with RegEx (POSIX).

I'd like to pull out a specific number from my text, and ignore other numbers.

For example. I'm interested in '55', but want to ignore 2055, 555, 0550, etc.

Frustratingly, I can't reliably say what would be and the beginning or the end of the number, e.g. unknown if ' 55', ':55', ' 55', ' 55 ', etc. I've just got to assume is anything but a number (or nothing at all).

Thanks!

Comment: Something like: `^[^\d]*55[^\d]*$` ?

Comment: The boundary character may help `\b55\b`. Here is a discussion including digit searches as your example http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a feature in regular expressions where you can limit the search string to that string and that string only.

To do this, you must prepend `\<` and append `\>`  to the string you are searching for.

In your case, you would use `\<55\>` as your search string.

You need to have the backslashes included.

Comment: I've never seen this before. Do you have a reference for this anywhere? (PS: those are backslashes)

Comment: From the same link provided above by Pierre Lafortune, scroll to the bottom where it describes this use in the section "GNU Word Boundaries".

Thanks also for the proof reading help!

Comment: Well that's pretty dang neato. Thanks!

Comment: Also, on page 185 of A Practical Guide to Linux by Mark G. Sobell [https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Guide-Commands-Editors-Programming/dp/013308504X/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8]

Answer (score 2):

```
^(.*[^\d])?55([^\d].*)?$
```

This will accept anything that has a 55 in it such that the 55 is not adjacent to any other numbers. For instance, it would accept:

```
1: 55
```

But not

```
Num: 556
```

This way there can be other numbers in the line, just so long as the number 55 exists somewhere by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use negative look-behind and negative look-ahead like so

```
(?<!\d)(55)(?!\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/388)
Explanation:

```
(?<!            # Negative Look-Behind
  \d            # <digit 0-9>
)               # End of Negative Look-Behind
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  55            # "55"
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
  \d            # <digit 0-9>
)               # End of Negative Look-Ahead
```